# React unmounts and remounts layout components using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, react-dom

I have react-router set up and a `Switch` component that renders some Page components. All my components render the same layout (for now. Later it will be parametric). My page components "inject" content to the layout so I can't have the layout component wrap my outer switch component. It has to be used as a child from within the page components.

```
// Sample code:

// app.js
const App = () => (
    <LanguageProvider defaultLanguage="el" languages={languages}>
        <PathProvider>
            <MenuProvider menu={appMenu}>
                <TemplateProvider injectedComponents={uiComponentOverrides} toolBar={toolBar}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" />
                        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/overview" component={OverviewIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/federation" component={FederationIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/clubs" component={ClubsIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/athletes" component={AthletesIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/athletes/:id" component={AthleteDetails} />
                        <Route exact path="/officials" component={OfficialsIndex} />
                        <Route component={EmptyPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </TemplateProvider>
            </MenuProvider>
        </PathProvider>
    </LanguageProvider>
);


// Sample of a page component
// dashboard-page.js

export const DashboardIndex = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    return (
        <AppFullPage key="page-component" title={t('Home.Index.WelcomeTitle')}>
            <p>Dashboard content</p>
        </AppFullPage>
    );
};

// The AppFullPage component is the layout component. Content is injected to it through the title, subtitle, toolbar, menu and children props.
```

Even though the final html render is the same from the layout skeleton (it only differs inside the *slot* parts of the layout), react unmounts and remounts the whole layout tree.

I can understand react re-rendering the whole tree. React sees a different top component (the page component is different for every location). So react renders the new component and creates a new virtual dom.

What I can't understand is unmounting and remounting of the top html elements since they didn't change. The top div didn't change. The language picker dropdown in my header menu didn't change. The application menu in the left didn't change. Yes, they where rendered from different components but they are the same output.

If react compares the outputs of successive renders and only changes what is needed, then why the components are unmounted and remounted?

This behavior breaks animations and other behavior of components (eg I would like a dropdown in the common layout space to remain open even after a page change, but since it is unmounted and remounted, it loses state).

**How can I instruct react to not remount identical components?**

Or

**How can I achieve my goal of letting the page inject content in the layout?**

Is using portals a candidate for a solution?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Components should only remount if reconciliation sees a spot in the tree where 1) component type changed or 2) key changed

Comment: @NicholasTower I updated the question with sample code

Comment: @NicholasTower I tried same keys, wrapped the components in divs, used the render prop instead of component prop etc, but the common layout components remount on every page change

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your layout component? Are you sure it unmounts/remounts or re-renders?

If component unmounts - there should be some kind of conditional rendering, check that place. If components re-renders then check props to be sure they not changes when they must not.

Comment: I have put a console.log code in unmounting even of one of my common layout components (a dropdown that is always visible in the upper right corner of my layout). It unmounts and mounts gain on each location change even when the component stays visibly the same. I don't mind re-rendering. I expect react to fully render the new page with the new layout. I wouldn't expect to unmount and re-mount the identical components though.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can use render prop function instead of component prop in the <Route  ...  to prevent remounting.

I assume this will help https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/simple-guide-for-layouts-in-react-router-e32b26c12cee

Comment: I did what you say but it didn't help. The example you gave does not address my needs. 1) A layout does not know what page it will render. 2) A page does not know which layout will be used. 3) The components that define each page choose which layout to use (this means we may have different layouts on each url location). 4) The components that define each page should inject the content that will fill the slots of the layout through layout's render props. 5) The slots are well defined and the same for every layout (even if a particular layout doesn't render some of the slots)

Comment: In this case the diffing algorithm will get new elements (components DashboardIndex, OverviewIndex and other) each time route changes, and unmount each time.

"Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch"

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Answer (score 0):

Move your common layout components outside of the switch. Then use the location to determine your dynamic props.

```
<AppFullPage>
  <Switch>
    {all routes}
  </Switch>
</AppFullPage>
```

```
const AppFullPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    switch(location.pathname) {
      case 'dashboard': {
        setTitle(t('Home.Index.WelcomeTitle'));
      }
      ... the rest of your cases
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

}
```

This code is just an example, idk if it will work exactly as is but should give you an idea

Comment: AppFullPage should be page agnostic. It is just a layout. It will be in a library. The end-developer will use the library and provide pages that use this layout (or not). The pages should also be layout agnostic.Each page should be self-contained (meaning all the sections depending on that page should be contained within the same component). I don't want parts of the page scattered in other places.
Also, not all pages share the same layout. So I can't have my layout outside the switch.

Comment: Then your only option is to use redux or context rather than component state to save the data. The reason everything is unmounting/remounting is because its all nested under the switch, so its a completely new component.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to use is below. *This is a hack workaround to make it possible for nested pages to provide content to the layout in the levels above. I will try to improve it.*

What I am doing is creating a context (`LayoutContext`) that would hold the rendered elements for each slot by slot name. The `Layout` component holds the state of the context and passes the section setter to the descendands through the context.

I created helper components (`LayoutSectionPlaceHolder` and `LayoutSection`) to encapsulate the use of hooks and memoization wherever needed.

Within the `Layout` component we render a `LayoutSectionPlaceHolder` element in each place we want content to be injected by the page.

Each page component should return one or more `LayoutSection` elements and only that. We don't want the page itself to render anything. We only want it to push(inject) content to the layout whenever that content changes. `LayoutSection` component is responsible for injecting the content provided to it as the children prop, to the `Layout`.

This solution is a hack because in the first render of the page, all slots are empty (no content has been set yet). And this is because content is provided first time when the page element is mounted, using `useLayoutEffect` hook, and then whenever the content changes.

That being said, **it would be nice if React provided a build-in mechanism of reverse context (from children to parent) as an inversion of control pattern**

```
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useLayoutEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/page1' render={() => <Layout><Page1 /></Layout>} />
                <Route exact path='/page2' render={() => <Layout><Page2 /></Layout>} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

const LayoutSlotSetterContext = createContext(() => {});

const useLayoutSlotSetter = () => {
    const { setSection } = useContext(LayoutSlotSetterContext);
    return setSection;
};

const useLayoutSectionUpdater = (slotName, content, slotSetter) => useLayoutEffect(() => slotSetter(slotName, content), [content, slotName, slotSetter]);
const useLayoutSectionContent = (sectionName) => {
    const { sections: { [sectionName]: section } = {} } = useContext(LayoutSlotSetterContext);
    return section;
};

const LayoutSectionPlaceHolder = ({ section }) => {
    const content = useLayoutSectionContent(section);
    return content === undefined ? null : content;
};

const LayoutSection = ({ section, children }) => {
    const slotSetter = useLayoutSlotSetter();
    useLayoutSectionUpdater(section, children, slotSetter);
    return null;
};

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => () => console.log('unmounted: [Layout]'), []);
    const reducer = useCallback((sections, { section, content }) => {
        if (!section) return sections;
        return {
            ...sections,
            [section]: content,
        };
    }, []);
    const [sections, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});
    const setSection = useCallback((section, content) => dispatch({ section, content }), [dispatch]);

    return (
        <LayoutSlotSetterContext.Provider value={{ sections, setSection }}>
            {children}
            <Menu /> {/* <-- this element is the same for every page. It should never unmounted */}
            <Header /> {/* <-- this element is the same for every page. It should never be unmounted */}
            <div>
                <LayoutSectionPlaceHolder section='content' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <LayoutSectionPlaceHolder section='secondsMounted' /> seconds mounted [<LayoutSectionPlaceHolder section='page' />]
            </div>
        </LayoutSlotSetterContext.Provider>
    );
};

const Menu = () => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => () => console.log('unmounted: [Menu]'), []);
    return (
        <ul>
            <li>
                <Link to='/page1'>Page 1</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to='/page2'>Page 2</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
};

const Header = () => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => () => console.log('unmounted: [Header]'), []);
    const counter = useSecondsMounted();
    return <h2>{counter} seconds mounted [header]</h2>;
};

const Page1 = () => {
    const counter = useSecondsMounted();
    return (
        <>
            <LayoutSection section='content'>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
            </LayoutSection>
            <LayoutSection section='page'>Page 1</LayoutSection>
            <LayoutSection section='secondsMounted'>{counter}</LayoutSection>
        </>
    );
};

const Page2 = () => {
    const counter = useSecondsMounted();
    return (
        <>
            <LayoutSection section='content'>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
            </LayoutSection>
            <LayoutSection section='page'>Page 2</LayoutSection>
            <LayoutSection section='secondsMounted'>{counter}</LayoutSection>
        </>
    );
};

/** Counts the seconds a component stays mounted */
const useSecondsMounted = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0); // used for illustration purposes. The counter increases +1/sec. It should do that as long as it is visible in the page
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => setCounter((c) => c + 1), [1000]);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);
    return counter;
};

export default App;
```